# Get mouse position coordinates for RGBDemo

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, position, mouse, coordinates

I realise that some similar questions have been asked but I'm still stuck.

I am trying to write a small section of code that will give the x,yz coordinages of the mouse when clicked on a 3D scene that was reconstructed using the kinect. My aim is to create a 'go to' function for a robotic arm.

I think I need to find the mouse xy position in the window frame, and then transform that into the frame of the screen before finally the frame of the scene. Is this right? Also I can't figure out how to read the depth value from the pixel?

I am fairly new to visual studio and c++ programming and I'm struggling to write the correct code. I'm not sure whether I should create a new class and include it or just to slot it straight into the viewer project.

Here's what I've written but I'm sure it need altering.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Toby

```
void get_point_position_MOUSE(int event, int x, int y, int flags,
    void* depthMapZ) {
if (CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN == event) {
    if (DISP_IMAGE_DEPTH != IPL_DEPTH_32F) {
        write_on_buffer(
                g_strdup_printf(
                        "This only supports IPL_DEPTH_32F images.\n"));
        return;
    }
    if (selectionMode != POINT_SEL_MODE_MOUSE) {
        write_on_buffer(g_strdup_printf("X: %f Y: %f\n", (float) x,
                (float) y));
        CvPoint3D32f points = getWorldCo_Ords((float) x, (float) y,
                (float) CV_IMAGE_ELEM((IplImage*) disparityMap, int, y, x));
        write_on_buffer(g_strdup_printf("X: %f Y: %f Z: %f\n", points.x,
                points.y,
                (float) CV_IMAGE_ELEM((IplImage*) disparityMap, int, y, x)));
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using RGBDemo, there are methods in the RGBImage than gives you that information.
First you need to map your point from your 2D image to the 2D Depth Image (in case your image has been and create a cv::Point pt with those coordinates.
Then from the ntk::RGBDImage you can call the function:

```
cv::Point3f p3f = rgbdimage->calibration()->depth_pose->unprojectFromImage(pt, rgbdimage->depth()(pt));
```

this point contains the 3D coordinates of the world (not sure but I think it is in meters)

Hope it helped!